# Reputação caindo drasticamente

Tags: suporte

O que devo fazer quando algum usuário te sabota e negativa todas as suas respostas fazendo com que sua reputação caia drasticamente? Perdi mais de 50 pontos em menos de 10 minutos por um usuário que, aparentemente por motivos pessoais, negativou todas as minhas respostas. :(

Comment: O proprio sistema detecta isso e irá reverter e provavelmente a atitude deste usuário será notada pelas ferramentas dos moderadores e talvez ele tome um suspensão

Comment: Lembrando que a reversão não é instantânea, o script roda uma vez por dia: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/401803 - então aguarde até amanhã, se foi o mesmo usuário, os votos serão revertidos.

Comment: Agora devo ressaltar uma critica a sua atuação no site, não leve a mal, mas você tem respondido muitas perguntas que deveriam ser fechadas como duplicatas, "suporte técnico" até que é legal e útil, mas se já existe uma pergunta com respostas com resolvem o problema de uma nova pergunta use o botão Fechar ou Flag para sinalizar como dup, não fique gerando respostas para perguntas que deveriam ser duplicatas, a não ser que seja um problema muito especifico na maioria dos casos existem ótimas respostas em perguntas mais antigas, pesquise antes de responder. Leve como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Obrigado pela crítica, vou leva-la em consideração. Quanto a essa reversão vou ficar no aguardo então :)

Comment: Eu também levei o "serial down", então por inferência sabemos quem foi o autor.

Comment: O problema já foi identificado e está sendo acompanhado. Peço que aguardem mais um pouco para que os procedimentos automáticos possam surtir efeito.

Comment: @JrD Só lembrando que o sistema encerra a contagem de votos diárias às 22h, então não estranhe se a reputação for revertida apenas nesse horário (talvez só amanhã, dependendo de quão sobrecarregado o servidor está).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss *[pedantic-mode on]* Na verdade essa contagem diária encerra à meia-noite em UTC, que pode ser 21h, 22h, ou qualquer outro horário, dependendo de onde vc está :-) (atualmente no horário de Brasília, equivale a 21h - se for no horário de verão, aí é 22h)  Mas segundo o [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/401803), o script de reversão roda às 03:00 UTC (atualmente meia-noite no horário de Brasília - ou 01:00 durante o horário de verão) *[pedantic-mode off]*

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu optei por ser mais prático e passar um horário específico, mesmo que incorreto, para não fazer ninguém ter que calcular xD

Comment: Tudo bem, o horário em que a reputação é revertida é meio que indiferente. Só queria saber mesmo se o carinha ia fazer a sacanagem e sair impune... mas já que o sistema cuida desse tipo de ação tá tudo bem xD

Comment: @JrD o sistema aqui é bravo e rígido. >:)