# Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?

Tags: suporte, faq, destaque, perguntas, fechamento

Vou citar apenas os principais erros.

Observe estas orientações para **editar sua pergunta**, deixando-a **viável para respostas**.

## 1. Não poste enunciados

Disparado o maior problemas das perguntas hoje é que a pessoa coloca um enunciado do que ela deseja e espera que alguém resolverá para ela, talvez colocando um código que executa o que ela quer.

O site não existe para isso. Inclusive quem responde esse tipo de pergunta está incentivando o erro.

Mesmo perguntas que tem uma descrição bem detalhada do problema, se não tem um problema específico, se não tem código, e não tem todas informações necessárias, a pergunta não é boa e deve ser fechada, e quem sabe negativada dependendo da qualidade.

Poucas perguntas sem código que a pessoa tentou são válidas, em geral só as que são conceituais e a pessoa só que quer saber o que significa um termo ou conceito geral.

Mesmo que tenha algum código, mas ele nada tenha a ver com o problema **específico** da pergunta, então ele está ali só para encher linguiça e a pergunta ainda é inaceitável. Mesmo que a descrição do problema seja muito detalhada, se você só quer que alguém faça para você, dê alguma dica, uma luz, um norte, uma ajudinha, não é aqui que conseguirá algo.

Perguntas cuja resposta seja algo parecido com sim ou não costumam cair nisso, porque e pessoa depois de saber que dá para fazer aquilo ela quer que alguém mostre como fazer. Pedido de exemplos, *links*, indicações não deixam de ser só um enunciado e não um problema específico.

Mesmo que a resposta seja simples, se você não tentou fazer e está enfrentando um problema específico, não tem uma pergunta válida aqui, perguntar *como fazer*, por mínimo que seja, não é adequado.

## 2. Poste todas informações

Outro problema é a falta de informações suficientes para responder aqui. Entendemos que a pessoa nem sempre sabe tudo o que deve colocar. Mas isso é sinal que ela está fazendo algo mais avançado do que ela consegue no momento e deveria tentar o simples primeiro, adquirir os fundamentos, construir o conhecimento passo por passo e aí ir entendendo o processo de desenvolvimento de software.

Algumas pessoas até acham que tem todas as informações e respondem. Quase sempre dá errado e não era aquilo, e mesmo que acerte por coincidência não é um bom motivo. E o acerto não é o autor da pergunta considerar certo, em geral, passa ter três erros: a pergunta, a resposta e a aceitação como resposta certa. É ruim para todos, mesmo que alguns não percebam.

A pergunta deve ter **tudo** o que é **necessário**. O código que fez e testou, o que está acontecendo de errado, que erro dá, quando dá, onde acontece, com que entrada de dados, ou seja, como reproduzi-lo, e o que deveria acontecer para ser correto.

> Se você colocou tudo, mas colocou demais, temos que olhar todo seu código, se não tem apenas um problema determinado, está só pedindo ajuda, procure um modo de reduzir o código para só reproduzir o que precisa. Podemos responder outros pontos mas em perguntas diferentes. Tem dicas e mais detalhes na versão longa.
>
> --- [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt (curto)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-sopt-vers%C3%A3o-curta)

Ao mesmo tempo, não deve ter mais informação do que deveria para verificar o problema. Aprenda fazer [um exemplo, mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/101). Não coloque o fardo em quem vai te ajudar. Facilite a vida dessa pessoa para ela te ajudar. Você só vai atrair bons programadores para seu problema se ele foi bem definido e você demonstra que está se esforçando em ajudar a todos. A pergunta pode ter todas as informações e não estar clara, porque você tem que estudar todo seu problema para poder responder, precisa objetividade no que é o problema **específico**. Isole só o seu problema para apresentar.

Quando uma pergunta é fechada como não clara é porque falta informação, quase sempre não é porque o texto está confuso. Mas verifique se o texto está claro. Releia várias vezes, melhore. Veja se pode melhorar a ortografia e gramática. Não amontoe tudo. Aprenda a formatar. Escreva um texto que mostre seu problema para quem não sabe sobre ele. Se você achar que pode jogar qualquer informação e a pessoa vai adivinhar o que é, não só você está errado, mas demonstra falta de noção mínima de como uma pergunta deve ser feita, qualquer que seja o lugar dessa pergunta, e isso é sinal de sérios problemas. Problemas esses muito maiores do que não conseguir resolver uma questão de programação. Isso espantará e desmotivará bons programadores de te ajudar, pois eles sabem que dificilmente sairá coisa boa dali.

Não basta descrever o problema, é preciso fornecer todos os detalhes **de forma específica**. Se não sabe o que é ser específico procure aprender sobre, vai ajudar muito na sua vida.

Se precisar de interações como ocorre em um fórum para poder responder a pergunta adequadamente, ou ela não é clara, ou é em um formato não aceito para um site de perguntas e respostas. Este site **NÃO** é um fórum de discussão.

Novamente, se não sabe todas as informações que precisa colocar, e o que é gordura desnecessária que deveria ser cortada, provavelmente está fazendo algo mais complexo do que consegue no momento. Nós podemos lhe ajudar com coisas mais básicas.

## 3. Outros problemas

Há outros problemas, como a pergunta ser sobre TI, mas não sobre desenvolvimento de software, a pergunta pedir opinião das pessoas, ou a pergunta exigir produzir um livro para explicar tudo, ou ainda ter várias perguntas em uma só. E a pergunta pode já ter sido respondida, ainda que mais genericamente, em outra pergunta já feita antes.

## 4. Redigindo uma boa pergunta

Se você não sabe o que é **um problema específico**, então você provavelmente precisa aprender, pois isso é fundamental para decompor tudo o que for fazer em programação.

Lembre-se que o mundo não gira em torno de você. Você precisa de ajuda, demonstre boa vontade e comprometimento com seu problema para convencer outras pessoas de que ele vale a pena. Inclusive, tente fazer ele interessante para ensinar outras pessoas, pois esse é o principal objetivo do site.

Só dá para ter respostas de qualidade quando a pergunta tem qualidade. Você chegou aqui porque o site preza pela qualidade. Não queira tentar mudar isso postando uma pergunta ruim, faça ela ser boa, vamos adorar te ajudar.

As pessoas mais antigas do site são experientes. Se acha que sabe mais do que elas, demonstre isso melhorando sua pergunta para ela ficar adequada.

Edite sua pergunta e tente fazer ela ficar em melhores condições. Não poste perguntas repetidas, mesmo que mudando alguns detalhes, e menos ainda sem resolver os problemas de elaboração da pergunta original. E não basta mudar um pequeno detalhe, tem que resolver todos os problemas de elaboração da pergunta original. Não tente burlar o sistema, isso só piorará sua situação.

**Não peça ajuda, faça uma pergunta**!

## 5. Alguns *links* para acompanhar e obter mais informação:

- [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/101)
- [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101) ([e completa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs))
- [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/101)
- [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/137387)
- [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/297025)

[Retornar para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Podem por mais links que achem necessários. E usem para instruir as pessoas.

Comment: Isso mesmo! O mais importante é mostrar que está se esforçando para resolver a referida questão. Demonstrar esforço não é apenas dizer que não sabe, mas sim mostrar todos os indícios que realmente teve algum trabalho em tentar resolver a referida questão.

Comment: Caro @Solkarped não entendi bem quem está se esforçando, se é o Maniero ou se você se refere a qualquer autor de perguntas.

Comment: Me referir à toda e qualquer pessoa que de alguma forma venha realizar uma pergunta no stack overflow. O MANIERO, é um dos **MELHORES** moderadores desta plataforma. Como é notável, o mesmo vem desempenhando um ótimo e relevante trabalho nessa plataforma.

Comment: Estou esperando ver quem discorda (-3 até agora) da postagem aqui formular uma nova postagem com dicas de seus proprios pontos de vista de como usuários devem atuar nos tipos de problemas mais comuns ao formular perguntas no site principal. Porque se existe discordância então no mínimo teriam que formular uma boa dica/instrução para ajudar no site também.

Comment: Eu sugeriria um título um pocuo mais "convidativo", tipo "A minha pergunta tem algum problema?" ou "Como melhorar minha pergunta?". Esse pode parecer um pouco agressivo, afirmando que o usuário que recém entrou na plataforma está errado ao fazer a pergunta (mesmo que esteja)

Comment: Por favor, já são quatro pessoas com opinião contrária a orientação. É uma questão de administração do site e envolve a todos. Não se cale, contribua com o Stack Overflow em Português, exponha sua visão, mostre-nos o seu ponto de vista, faça uso da palavra. Não é o pedido de uma justificativa para o seu voto mas peço sim a abordagem a uma outra visão.

Comment: Isso me parece mais discussão de panelinha, novatos ou seja o que for, nunca que irão ler esse conteúdo, vejo usuário com 1 ponto, acabou de se cadastrar que vai logo postando perguntas, ou parafraseando o Maniero, "pedindo código pronto", nem esquentam em navegar na comunidade, esse tipo de tópico acaba por chover no molhado, sendo que os leitores do meta sempre são os velhos de casa que apontam "Como sobreviver no SOpt" aos novatos. Creio que deveria ter algum recurso no site, visível para os novatos sobre os tópicos com esse teor, acima do campo de postagem do pergunta/resposta, um "alert"

Comment: "Não peça ajuda, faça uma pergunta!"

Acho que esse é o ponto. Acredito que uma parte considerável de usuários procure ajuda com o site (isso não é um problema). Entendo a questão de "querer código pronto" ou de não demonstrar que se esforçou e concordo, mas, no mundo do TI é muito comum sermos atribuídos a tarefas das quais ainda não temos todos os conhecimentos ou condições de resolver e, acredito que, seja muitas vezes nesse momento que os usuários procuram o SOPT. Se o problema da pessoa é "algo mais avançado do que ela consegue fazer no momento", talvez seja por isso que ela está aqui.

Comment: Por fim, acredito que dar dislike na pergunta até que a pessoa acabe sendo kickada da plataforma afugenta novos usuários que estão aprendendo programação e / ou iniciando no mercado de trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Prezadíssimos(as),

De forma a contribuir vou colocar aqui algumas considerações que acredito ser importantes em termos de prioridade. Voltei a participar da comunidade e queria dar um Feedback do que senti. Lógico, estou aberto a críticas e opiniões contrárias são bem-vindas! Afinal o importante é aprender e melhorar sempre (digo isso para mim mesmo todos os dias)

**1 - Dificuldade em escrever razoavelmente**

Acredito que uma postura de dar um "downvote" em casos de erros demais de português, não contribui para o aprendizado da pessoa. Usar os comentários para sugerir ou usar um esforço de edição, vale a pena.

**2 - Detectar melhor o problema de querer solução pronta**

Precisamos ver como incentivar melhor isso: leia o manual, participe de um teste e ganhe pontos de reputação (não sei se isso é possível). Existe essa possibilidade? Com isso a pessoa participa de um teste para justamente avaliar perguntas e entender o por quê elas são diferentes e aprender como formular melhor. Não adianta, se a pessoa tem dificuldade de escrever, geralmente tem dificuldade de interpretar e, nesses casos fica difícil ajudar, mas precisamos ter a postura de realmente ajudar.

**3 - Diferenciar a ingenuidade da falta de ética profissional**

Eu fiquei profundamente chateado quando dei um código pronto para uma solução e a pessoa copiou PARTE do código, nem leu, e já perguntou: tá dando erro na linha tal. Claro! copiou e colou metade do código! Lógico que não ia funcionar.

Comportamentos assim estragam a comunidade e prometi a mim mesmo que vou dar sempre fragmentos de código para que a pessoa estude. Não temos obrigação de contribuir voluntariamente para trabalhar para os outros. Isso é errado e eu desaprovo também qualquer atitude que faça isso e não farei mais.

**4 - Perguntas abertas demais**

Notou uma pergunta aberta demais, tem que sinalizar no comentário sua pergunta está aberta, leia aqui para entender. Ontem tinha um pergunta que não perguntava absolutamente nada. Recomendei um livro para a pessoa. Ué. Quando não se sabe o que quer, qualquer coisa serve.

Perguntas abertas precisam ser "advertidas" geralmente vêm de membros novos que lógico que não leram o guia.

**5 - Melhoria no mecanismo de fechar perguntas**

Entendo que a timeline das perguntas está ficando lotada demais de perguntas ruins (não estou dizendo desinteressantes, mas mal elaboradas). Não há como antes de publicar a pergunta no ar, de verdade, passar pelo menos pela análise de sei lá, 3 ou 5 membros (número ímpar) para não dar empate, para votar: vai para o ar ou não? Se não for para o ar, já devolve o motivo e a pessoa tem que aprender, se ela não se esforçar nunca vai conseguir postar uma pergunta se quer!

**6 - Stackoverflow não é curso grátis e consultoria de ensino gratuito de textão**

Já cometi esse erro: responder preguntas usando quilômetros de textos, virando UM ARTIGO. Resposta não é artigo. Resposta precisa ser pontual - entendo dessa forma. Portanto as perguntas devem ser diretas ao ponto. Começou com resposta grande demais, virou consultoria. Acho que precisamos adotar um pouco mais a postura do Stackoverflow internacional. Tem respostas excelentes por exemplo de caras da Google que são curtinhas. Por quê? Pergunta bem formulada.

Caí na besteira de responder uma pergunta aberta demais: Pra que serve a máquina de estados de um objeto. Fiquei motivado em dar um baita exemplo, mas no final me arrependi. Custou muito tempo meu em participar e achei isso ruim. Teve gente que leu achou legal. Acho que respostas longas deveriam existir só para perguntas com premiação. Porque o tempo que se gasta elaborar uma pergunta para um, desculpe a expressão, zé moleza que não quer sentar a bunda na cadeira para estudar, é chato.

**7 - Stackoverflow não é periódico científico**

Escrever de forma mais próxima, coloquial, sendo agradável. Evitar qualquer tipo de escrita científica. Aqui não tem qualis A, B ou C...
Não é periódico científico. Ok, as vezes me pego escrevendo assim aqui e acho errado. Afinal sou cientista e estou em um doutorado.

**8 - Levar os comentários mais "na esportiva"**

Isso não é um email formal de empresa, onde ficará registrado A, B ou C sobre você. Pelo amor de Deus, precisamos de um espaço sem filtros, mais bacana, acessível e aconchegante. Deve ser legal frequentar aqui, mesmo que seja uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas, as vezes pessoas sentem a necessidade de se expressar com um pouco de emoção, entendem? Logicamente, existem pessoas mais acessíveis, descoladas, mais formais, mais empáticas ou frias. Ok, mas aqui deveria ser um refúgio, um lugar onde podemos ter uma convivência agradável e sem filtros. Agora, se for para continuar da forma que está, prefiro não participar mais.
Vou dar um exemplo: Ontem, um cara deu uma resposta no comentário +- assim num comentário: eu sei o que é Pattern Match. Deu vontade de responder, sabe o c******* mas fui educado COM FILTRO e respondi: ok, não disse que vc não sabe. Isso é chato.

Comment: A postagem **antes do edit** eu achei interessante, mas ficou meio que "depoimento pessoal", e não algo que agregue muito ao intuito original da postagem, que é de orientar quem teve pergunta fechada. Mas acho que agregava algum valor (colateral) para quem vai responder, de fato (só que aí já não seria resposta da "pergunta" daqui, que é mais uma orientação). De qq forma, acho que é uma leitura interessante, e é bom você ter tido esses insights. O que eu mais resumiria pra quem responde pergunta no site principal é: concentre-se em boas perguntas. O resto "contamina".

Comment: @Bacco obrigado pelas considerações.

Comment: "*dar um "downvote" em casos de erros demais de português, não contribui para o aprendizado da pessoa*" - mas o objetivo do site não é ensinar português. Saber escrever de forma minimamente inteligível é pré-requisito pra poder participar do site (para aprender português, a pessoa deve recorrer a outros lugares). E muitos confundem o downvote com ofensa pessoal, mas ele é para classificação de conteúdo (se está mal escrito, não contribui para formar o repositório de conhecimento, e portanto merece um downvote sim). Se for editado e melhorado, o voto pode ser revisto e até virar upvote

Comment: @hkotsubo mas aí que está! Trabalhamos com lógica, qual é a possibilidade de uma pessoa que escreve mal ler um guia? Mas ok. Ela vem aqui, faz a pergunta e vamos arrebentar e fechar a pergunta? Ok... você está certo, mas não dizer a pessoa o porque ela errou e fechar a pergunta, vai melhorar o conhecimento dela? Vai contribuir? Acho que não. Mas novamente te digo: vc não está errado.

Comment: Se a pessoa não consegue nem ler um guia e seguir as instruções, então ela deve trabalhar esses pontos **antes** de participar do site, no lugar adequado (como já disse, não é nosso intuito ensinar isso, inclusive a base de usuários ativos nem é de professores de português, aqui definitivamente não é o lugar certo para aprender a ler e escrever).

Comment: Qual a possibilidade de uma pessoa que escreve mal e não lê guias se tornar programadora? No fim este post acabou virando o mesmo desabafo de sempre e que já foi discutido diversas vezes, até cansou, eu nem participo mais de tanto que eu já participei e sei que ele não leva a lugar algum, ninguém vai mudar de opinião. Vou repetir o que sempre falo para as pessoas e tem vários posts meus sobre isso: seja a mudança que quer no site. Não peça para os outros fazerem trabalho voluntário, faça você. Todos aqui já fizeram muito, até que percebe que não vale o esforço. Depois que fizer bastante, volte

Comment: E sobre "*dizer a pessoa o porque ela errou*", bem, o site recebe em média cerca de 100 perguntas diárias (a maioria com problemas), e é inviável comentar em todas. Já tentamos muito, ainda tentamos até hoje, mas por experiência própria digo que não é efetivo: a maioria ignora os comentários, alguns xingam a gente, e uma ínfima minoria de fato melhora as perguntas. Por causa disso, chega uma hora que cansa, como aliás muitos já cansaram, então hoje temos poucos que ainda tentam comentar e ajudar, mas como já disse, pouco adianta.

Comment: Dito isso, gosto da ideia da pergunta começar fechada e ser analisada por outros usuários antes de ir para o ar :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo a ideia é boa, mas poderia ter um ponto aonde isso seria desativado, por exemplo um usuário com excelente participação, porque burocracia é bom por um lado e ruim por outro, mas no geral seria mesmo ótimo se fosse assim.

Comment: Prezados, me considero iniciante do SOpt, e sempre li as regras sobre como a postagem precisa ter para ser respondida. Procuro seguir à risca, dar exemplos, mas desculpe o termo, é "broxante" em apenas dois minutos de post você ver downvote na sua pergunta. Olhando a timeline daqui do SOpt, e fazendo uma comparação com o SO original, a quantidade de downvotes são horrendas. E as mesmas que eu faço aqui eu fiz lá e diferente da SOpt, o pessoal se mostra mais receptivo. Se tem uma coisa que o SOpt me fez é deixar de usa-lo e buscar por conta própria as soluções para as minhas dúvidas.

Comment: @hkotsubo "é inviável comentar em todas". É ainda mais frustrante receber downvotes e não receber feedback sobre o que poderia ser melhorado.

Seria interessante uma text-box para dar feedback junto com o downvote se o problema é "tempo".

Tanto o lado do perguntador e do solucionador podem ser mal educados, isto não justifica a falta de feedback ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Also, 100 perguntas é relativamente pouco considerando que qualquer um pode responder as perguntas :)

Comment: O SO possui um sistema de chat, que eu acho relativamente melhor que um sistema de comentários. As pessoas não podem solucionar o problema em conjunto devido a necessidade de adquirir "pontos", isso realmente tira seu "tempo"

Comment: @EduApps Concordo que é ruim e chato receber voto negativo sem saber o motivo, ainda mais quando achamos que não há nada errado com a pergunta/resposta. Mas sabe o que é pior e mais chato ainda? É quando vc comenta justificando o voto, e em vez da pessoa reconhecer o erro e melhorar o post, ela [responde assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN9u5.png) e/ou resolve [fazer isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7703/112052). Para evitar esse stress todo, muitos ficam com receio de comentar e acabam votando sem dizer nada (não que isso seja o ideal, mas infelizmente acontece).

Comment: Não estou dizendo que todos os votos sem comentário são por causa disso, claro, mas antes de achar que permitir o voto sem justificativa é um erro, sugiro que leia [este FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8788/112052), que explica os motivos de ser assim (e principalmente, porque parece que isso não mudará tão cedo).
E 100 perguntas por dia é muito se considerarmos a quantidade de usuários ativos (os que ainda participam com certa frequência). A maioria cansou pelos motivos já citados, e para os poucos que sobraram, 100 é muito sim

Comment: Um exemplo bem ilustrativo: olha a [quantidade de texto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8141/112052) pra explicar pro cara porque a pergunta dele não estava boa. Foi um esforço imenso, com a melhor das intenções: ajudá-lo a entender os problemas da pergunta e corrigi-los. Resultado: o cara [desistiu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8140/#comment31978_8141) ("*não vou mais fazer perguntas*") e ainda apagou a conta. Infelizmente essa é a regra, a gente explica, a pessoa não reconhece o problema e nada muda. Com o tempo isso desanima e as pessoas param de comentar...

Comment: Faz sentido o que você diz. Nesse seu ultimo exemplo realmente o cara esqueceu de enviar como ele definiu a classe Pesquisa. Na verdade, acho que eu entenderia melhor sentindo isso na pele. Mas deve haver uma solução para ambos os problemas. Pois perguntador reclama da conduta de alguém que quer ajudar. Mas perguntador não escreve pergunta minimamente correta.

Comment: Com a intenção de entender o seu lado, decidi ajudar [um cara na gringa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139068/why-does-my-php-unsubscribe-form-return-a-500-error). Acho que o que está rolando aqui é algo que comumente acontece no suporte de qualquer empresa. O "cliente" é leigo e não sabe como se expressar. Nós estamos tentando ajudá-lo, então nós devemos conduzi-lo e mostra-lo inconsistências até a solução. Se um cara se frustrar, é porque algo deu um gatilho, e claramente os dois lados devem evitar esse gatilho.

Comment: Perceba a minha  abordagem. Não utilizei "Você não forneceu um exemplo minimo e utilizável". Isso só iria deixar o cara bravo. Eu respondi pedindo para ele definir as variáveis que não estão presentes, o que levaria ele a criar um exemplo minimo e utilizável.